# How to set large amount of HTML in Vue.js template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new in Vue.js. I have a question about how to render a large amount of HTML in vue.js template.

So i put a HTML in my template thats like a 500 lines of plain HTML. And when i do

> npm run dev

the compiling is to slow, or don't finish the compiling.

```
<template>
  <div class="m-grid m-grid--hor m-grid--root m-page">
      <mobile-menu-partial></mobile-menu-partial>
      <header-partial></header-partial>

      <div>HTML goes here</div>  <------

      <footer-partial></footer-partial>
  </div>
</template>
```

So is there an easy way to make that? I searched everything but could not find any site for that question.

This is my HTML.

```
<div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-grid m-grid--hor-desktop m-grid--desktop m-body">
    <div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid  m-grid m-grid--ver m-container m-container--responsive m-container--xxl m-page__container">
        <div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-wrapper">
            <div class="section-contacts">
                <!-- CONTACTS -->
                <div class="m-content">
                    <div class="m-portlet">
                        <div class="m-portlet__body  m-portlet__body--no-padding">
                            <div class="row m-row--no-padding m-row--col-separator-xl">
                                <div class="col-xl-6">
                                    <div class="standard-widget">
                                        <div class="m-widget14">
                                            <div class="widget_header_menu margin-bottom-10">
                                                <div class="m-widget14__header">
                                                    <h3 class="m-widget14__title">Grups</h3>
                                                    <span class="m-widget14__desc">3 groups</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="m-widget14__header_menu">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-accent btn-md m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createGroupModal"><i class="la la-plus"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row align-items-center margin-bottom-15">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                                        <input class="form-control form-control-search m-input" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Search...">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row align-items-center margin-bottom-15">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="m-scrollable">
                                                        <div class="m-list-timeline m-list-timeline--skin-light">
                                                            <div class="m-list-timeline__items no-timeline">
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contacts-group.html">Group name</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contacts-group.html">3 Contacts</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contacts-group.html">Group name</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contacts-group.html">3 Contacts</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contacts-group.html">Group name</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contacts-group.html">3 Contacts</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-6">
                                    <div class="standard-widget">
                                        <div class="m-widget14">
                                            <div class="widget_header_menu margin-bottom-10">
                                                <div class="m-widget14__header">
                                                    <h3 class="m-widget14__title">Contacts</h3>
                                                    <span class="m-widget14__desc">5 contacts</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="m-widget14__header_menu">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-accent btn-md m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createContactModal"><i class="la la-plus"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row align-items-center margin-bottom-15">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
                                                        <input class="form-control form-control-search m-input" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Search...">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row align-items-center">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div class="m-scrollable">
                                                        <div class="m-list-timeline m-list-timeline--skin-light">
                                                            <div class="m-list-timeline__items no-timeline">
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__badge">
                                                                        <div class="m-widget4__img m-widget4__img--pic">
                                                                            <a href="contact.html">
                                                                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                                                                    <img src="assets/base/media/img/users/user2.jpg" alt="">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contact.html">Benson John</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contact.html">+385 99 416 9113</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__badge">
                                                                        <div class="m-widget4__img m-widget4__img--pic">
                                                                            <a href="contact.html">
                                                                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                                                                    <img src="assets/base/media/img/users/user1.jpg" alt="">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contact.html">Clark Anna</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contact.html">+385 99 416 9113</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__badge">
                                                                        <div class="m-widget4__img m-widget4__img--pic">
                                                                            <a href="contact.html">
                                                                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                                                                    <img src="assets/base/media/img/users/user4.jpg" alt="">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contact.html">Grohl Dave</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contact.html">+385 99 416 9113</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__badge">
                                                                        <div class="m-widget4__img m-widget4__img--pic">
                                                                            <a href="contact.html">
                                                                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                                                                    <img src="assets/base/media/img/users/user3.jpg" alt="">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contact.html">Porter Ella</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contact.html">+385 99 416 9113</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="m-list-timeline__item no-timeline">
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__badge">
                                                                        <div class="m-widget4__img m-widget4__img--pic">
                                                                            <a href="contact.html">
                                                                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                                                                    <img src="assets/base/media/img/users/user5.jpg" alt="">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <span class="m-list-timeline__text">
                                                                        <span class="timeline-title"><span class="clr-black-light"><a href="contact.html">Wood Kelly</a></span></span>
                                                                        <span class="timeline-subtitle"><span class="clr-grey"><a href="contact.html">+385 99 416 9113</a></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: 500 lines is even for a plain html file quite large.

Comment: I added my HTML to the question.

Comment: Break your html into reusable components. If you want to achieve performance try to lazy load the components. If your html is in bootstrap, I would suggest using `bootstrap-vue`.

Comment: Can't you break components into logical(container) components and presentational components?

Comment: How to do that? Can you give an example? Because i have like few modules like Contacts, Dashboard and etc. And every module has his own html like that HTML above just different.

Comment: I won't call this a large html template, unless you have 5000 lines, even that, I don't call it large. Just a quick comment first. You must have some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to define a template in Vue. For big templates I suggest to use X-Templates. Define a component referring template by id.

```
Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
  template: '#checkbox-template',
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
      title: 'Check me'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    check() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  }
});
```

And define a template in your html file with appropriate id. Example:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox-template">
  <div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check">
    <div :class="{ checkbox: true, checked: checked }"></div>
    <div class="title"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

[More and Source.](https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d)